# Passing data between classes with Signals in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, signals-slots

I have got two different classes that i need to connect using a signal that sends text in a variable from one class, to another.

The first class is a Matplotlib figure. I added a `QPushButton`in the navigation toolbar to access a `QDialog` (wich is the other class) with a `QLineEdit`. I need to send the text written in the `QLineEdit`to the Matplotlib figure´s class, using a variable, so i can create a note in the figure.

This is the code so far:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):

  list_of_notes = []         #I create a list to add text, each time i open the QDialog

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def printVariable(self, text):
    Dialog.lisf_of_notes.append(text)
    MatplotlibFigure().addNote()

    self.close()

class MatplotlibFigure(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

   self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

  def addNote(self):
   for i,s in enumerate(Dialog.list_of_notes):
     note = self.axes.annotate(i, xy=(0.2, 0.2))  #This is the note i want to create
     note.draggable()
     self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
```

So, when i press the button "Accept" in the `QDialog` i can see that the text is added to the list, each time that i open the dialog. But, when i want to create the note from the last object that i added to the list, in the for loop nothing happens.

What is the problem? Hope you can help me.

### ----------------Edit-----------------------------

I´ve made some modifications. I created a signal `mysignal` to emit the variable `text`, which have the text that i wrote in the `QDialog`.

This is the modificated code:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, my_figure):

    mysignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    self.my_figure = MatplotlibFigure()
    QDialog.__init__(self)

    self.connect(self.btn_accept, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.send_text)
    self.mysignal.connect(self.printVariable)

  def send_text(self):              #I get the text from the QLineEdit and send it using 
    text = self.lineEdit.text()     #the created signal
    self.mysignal.emit(text)

  def printVariable(self, text):
    self,my_figure.addNote(text) 
    self.close()

class MatplotlibFigure(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.notes_list =[]

  def openDialog(self, text):    #I open the QDialog clicking a button
    textMat = Dialog(text)
    textMat.exec_()

  def addNote(self, text):
    self.notes_list.append(text)

    notes = self.axes.annotate(text, xy=(0.2, 0.2), bbox = dict(facecolor="red"))
    notes.draggable()
    self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
```

So, i open the `QDialog` and i can write the text. It is added to the list correctly, but the note is still not drawn in the figure.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the line of code

```
MatplotlibFigure().addNote()
```

This line instantiates a **new** instance of the `MatplotlibFigure` class and calls the `addNote` method. But you don't want to make a new figure every time you open the dialog, you want to add the note to a (presumably) pre-existing instance of `MatplotlibFigure`.

Because you don't show the code where the `QDialog` is created, it is difficult to suggest options, but one would be to pass a reference to the existing `MatplotlibFigure` into the constructor of `QDialog`. For instance

```
class Dialog(QDialog):

  list_of_notes = []         

  def __init__(self, my_figure):
      self.my_figure = my_figure
      ...

  def printVariable(self, text):
      Dialog.list_of_notes.append(text)
      self.my_figure.addNote()

      self.close()
```

Modify your code where you create the `Dialog` to pass in a reference to the figure. For example `my_dialog = Dialog(reference_to_my_figure)`

I would also like to point out that storing the list of notes in a class attribute is not a particularly good coding practice. I don't think you even need to store the list of notes unless you are planning on reusing them (your current code adds all the previously added notes again, each time a new note is added. Something like this should work fine (I've included optional storing in a list if you really want to do that)

```
class Dialog(QDialog): 

  def __init__(self, my_figure):
      self.my_figure = my_figure
      ...

  def printVariable(self, text):
      self.my_figure.addNote(text)

      self.close()


class MatplotlibFigure(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
      #A lot of stuff in here
      self.notes_list = []
      self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

  def addNote(self, text):
      #optional
      self.notes_list.append(text)

      # now add the note to the figure
      note = self.axes.annotate(text, xy=(0.2, 0.2))  #This is the note i want to create
      note.draggable()
      self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
```

But be aware that all your notes are going to point to the same location on the figure `(0.2,0.2)` (I assume you will fix this in later code).

I would also like to recommend you do some Python tutorials on object oriented programming, specifically something that covers classes vs. instances (or objects), class attributes vs. instance attributes and how to design reusable classes. It looks like a few of your issues stem from you not quite understanding these concepts in full.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @three_pineapples and sorry for late reply, i had some problems with my pc these days. I`ve made some modifications, and i added the lines you told me, but i still have the same problem. You are rigth, i do not understand this concept perfectly, but i am learning a lot doing this. Thank you again for your help.